# open link with specific tab

Tags: jquery

in a page I have tabs like this

```
<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#tabs-1">1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-2">2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-3">3</a></li>
    </ul>

    <div id="tabs-1">
       1
    </div>


    <div id="tabs-2">
      2

    </div>
    <div id="tabs-3">
3
    </div>
</div>
```

and a submit button in a form

when I click on submit I need to open specific tab in the same page

Thanks

Comment: What signifies the particular tab to be selected?

Comment: When you submit a form the page redirects the `target` to the url specified in `action`. The ways around this are to either use AJAX or to submit into an iframe.

Comment: Are you using jquery-ui tabs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    $('#tabs').tabs();
    function select_tab(tabeName){
       $('#tabs').tabs('select', '#'+tabname);
    }
</script>
```

html Submit

```
<input name="" type="button" onclick='select_tab("tab1")' value="submit"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use jqueryui tabs this is possible in this manner;
When you click on the button it will select the second tab

***Loading jquery and jqueryui first***

```
<link href="css/smoothness/jquery-ui-1.9.0.custom.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-ui-1.9.0.custom.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $("#tabs").tabs();// initiate tabs with jqueryui
});
</script>
```

***Html code***

we can have the button outside the tab as well, but here i have included it inside the first tab

```
<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#tabs-1">1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-2">2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-3">3</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="tabs-1">
       1
       <input name="" type="button" onclick='$("#tabs").tabs( "select", "tabs-2" )' value="select tab2"/>
    </div>
    <div id="tabs-2">
      2

    </div>
    <div id="tabs-3">
     3
    </div>
</div>
```

example: [Jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/swarne27/LR8kb/1/)

Comment: does it work but after a second come back to first tab itself

Comment: it works perfectly, and it does not come back to first tab like u say

Comment: may be you have made some mistake, see carefully

Comment: I've posted a link to the demo in jsfiddle